# About PHP OpenGL

Tags: php, opengl

Hi all does have an thoughts on how to use OpenGL in php based web application

We would like to create a php web application using OpenGL,while searching I come across some comments on OpenGL [here](https://github.com/yoya/phpopengl/tree/master/php_opengl).

**ATTENTION:**

This extension is meant to run on desktop Client side from the
very command line. **I no way it is intended that they run under a web server!**

But at the same on below [forum](http://sourceforge.net/p/phpopengl/discussion/97539/thread/b6dfe295/#5059)

```
php4 => php5 migration.
not cvs, but git repository.
-<b> runnable as web application.</b>
```

is it possible to do OpenGL projects in PHP web application..means running on browsers

If so, please provide documentation,that will help us more

Comment: what are you talking about? Can you clarify your question?

Comment: i cant understand what you trying to do?

Comment: I am going to create a graphics tooth chart in php web application using opengl


http://www.opendental.com/manual/graphicaltoothchart.html

I am trying to copy the same from above link..the above tooth chart used opengl and directx

My plan is create the same in php based web application using opengl.I came to know that directx is not supported with php

Comment: You perhaps meant [WebGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL)? I cant fit OpenGL (client side) in PHP (server side)

Comment: Does webgl work with LAMP environment as server and MAC,WINDOWS as client environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe that there is any way to run OpenGL on the server-side, at least not with vanilla php. Php is just too slow to reliably serve the kind of real-time data that OpenGL requires. If you can get it running, congrats, you just developed a competitor to OnLive :)

From reading the link you sent, it looks like this project is intended as a proof-of-concept for binding OpenGL to php to be run locally *only*. That is, you can get a quick and easy OpenGL context set up for testing (again, *locally*) if you are more familiar with php development than C++. If you are looking to develop a web application (which it seems like you are) then I would definitely give [WebGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL) a look. What WebGL does is it binds OpenGL functionality to Javascript, which is then run in a browser. The difference between WebGL and this project is that in WebGL, your OpenGL code is sent to the client browser where it is then executed. This is much faster and allows for some pretty [spectacular](http://madebyevan.com/webgl-water/) effects.

Comment: Thanks all for pointing me to right direction.I will try webgl

Answer (score 0):

using php you can develop openGL app but that will run using cli not over the web
for web u have to switch Javascript lib like 3Js.
if you want standalone openGL app using php u can use phpOpenGL extension.
a demo code using php

```
<?php
 function display(){

  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2f(0.0, 0.5);

    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2f(-0.5, -0.5); 

    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex2f(0.5, -0.5);
  glEnd();

  glFlush();
 }

 glutInit($argv);

 glutInitWindowSize(400,400);
 glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA);
 glutCreateWindow('Draw Triangle');

 glutDisplayFunc('display');

 glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

 glutMainLoop();

exit (0);
?>
```